# How to get the size of the panel

Tags: java

I am trying to get the height and the width of the panel inside the Panel class,  but i'm not sure how.

My main class:

```
public class Pong extends JFrame 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(1000, 800);
        frame.setLocation(500, 150);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Pong");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setContentPane(new Paneel());
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
    }
}
```

My panel class:

```
public class Paneel extends JPanel 
{
    public Paneel() {

    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me out here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: JPanel inherits `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` from `JComponent`.

Comment: Do i have to make an instance of a new JPanel in order to do that? And would i have to add the panel?

Comment: No. You can just call those methods from within `Paneel`.

Comment: The odd thing is, the height and with are both 0 even if i add a button to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is using [getSize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getSize(java.awt.Dimension)), the other one more relevant to your example would be [getWidth()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getSize(java.awt.Dimension)) and [getHeight()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getHeight())

To get the width and height in your panel class:

```
public class Paneel extends JPanel 
{
    public Paneel() {
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
    }
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for :)

Edit:

> The odd thing is, the height and with are both 0 even if i add a button to it

It's probably 0 because you check it's sizes before actually "adding" it to the frame meaning it does not have a distincive size yet, run the following code and you'll see it's not 0:

Pong.java:

```
public class Pong extends JFrame 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Paneel panel = new Paneel();

        frame.setSize(1000, 800);
        frame.setLocation(500, 150);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Pong");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);

        panel.printSizes();
    }
}
```

Note we ask the panel to print it's size after it has been added to the frame

Paneel.java:

```
public class Paneel extends JPanel 
{
    public Paneel() {

    }

    public void printSizes() {
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        System.out.println(width);
        System.out.println(height);
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked when i moved it to paintComponent. You put me on the right track. Thanks

Comment: Great stuff, glad I could help :)